# BLE splitting string data

Tags: string, ble

I am working with BLE 4.2 (ESP32) that sends IMU (accel, gyro, mag) data to my mobile app (Android). Unfortunately, I can send only 20 bytes in one packet.

This is the code I have: (I am connecting the float raw data (ax, ay,...my, mz...etc) read from the accelerometer.)

```
char myConcatenation[20];
char myStr[","];
.
.
.
 sprintf(myConcatenation,"%3.2f%s%3.2f%s%3.2f%s%3.2f%s%3.2f%s%3.2f%s%3.2f%s%3.2f%s%3.2f%s%3.2f%s%3.2f%s%3.2f", ax, myStr, ay, myStr, az, myStr,gx,myStr, gy, myStr, gz, myStr, mx, myStr, my, myStr, mz, myStr, yaw, myStr, pitch, myStr, roll);
.
.
.
pCharacteristic->setValue(myConcatenation);

pCharacteristic->notify(); // Send the value to the app!
```

Do you know how to construct a code so I would notify the app with new data of 20 Byte length? For example, each packet constructed of every sensor reading:

```
1. (ax, ay, az) 
2. (gx, gy, gz) 
3. (mx, my, mz) 
4. (yaw, pitch, roll)
```

Thank you for any advice and patience with my poor programming skills.

Comment: How is this related to arduino?

Comment: I am using Arduino IDE and I didn't know where else to put this. Sorry if it doesn't fit the thread topic.